# Hurdles in geting organic search data from google analytics (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to get organic search data from google analytics (using this package

```
@google-analytics/data)
```

tried different dimensions and metrics but had no success
also using this https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/query-explorer/

The dimension defaultChannelGroup returns a channel list but I need specific channel "organic search" data

```
 await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
            property: `properties/${123456789}`,
           dimensions: [name: 'defaultChannelGroup ']
          });
```

the response i have received

```
"data": [
    {
      "dimensionValues": "Direct",
      "metricValues": ""
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": "Email",
      "metricValues": ""
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": "Organic Search",
      "metricValues": ""
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": "Organic Social",
      "metricValues": ""
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": "Organic Video",
      "metricValues": ""
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": "Paid Other",
      "metricValues": ""
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": "Paid Search",
      "metricValues": ""
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": "Referral",
      "metricValues": ""
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": "Unassigned",
      "metricValues": ""
    }
  ]
```

I nee specific  "dimensionValues": "Organic Search", data

any help or suggestion will be appreciated